# jenkins Post Build if statement

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

Doing Jenkins Declarative Pipeline,

So I'm looking for "**Post**" action that will send e-mail only if there is 1 file which exists and is biggger then 0kb.

Very similiar to bash function : if [-s]

I can do that in a bash script, but how is done in jenkins for POST BUILD:

See how is made in bash:

```
if [ -s "$file" ]
then
/usr/bin/mutt -s "Master  Failed 3Days" $emails -a $file < /dev/null
        exit 1
else
        echo "$file is empty."
/usr/bin/mutt -s "Master  Success 3Days" $emails_success -a $file < /dev/null
        exit 0
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach is working:
1. You are doing a global variable with your shell script in stage

```
result = sh(script: '''
if [ -s "$file" ]
then
/usr/bin/mutt -s "Master  Failed 3Days" $emails -a $file < /dev/null
        echo 'found'
else
        echo "$file is empty."
/usr/bin/mutt -s "Master  Success 3Days" $emails_success -a $file < /dev/null
        echo 'not'
fi
''', returnStdout: true).trim()
```

2. You are adding post definitions

```
post {
    always {
        script {
            if (result.contains('found')) {
                <your logic to sending email>
            }
        }
    }
}
```